# partial derivative of $x^{y^z}$

Tags: derivatives

Can someone tell me the correct partial derivative of $x^{y^z}$ on the variable z. I got two solutions:

$x^{y^z}\ln\left(x^y\right)$

and

$x^{y^z}y^z\ln x\ln y$

They both seem right to me so I am confused.
Which one is correct and why?

Comment: How do you have the order of operations?  Is it $x^{(y^z)}$ or $(x^y)^z$?

Comment: @SimpleArt I've never seen nested exponents meant to be evaluated from left to right. Especially when you have to write `x^{y^z}` to make it render correctly, I would think there is little to no ambiguity. If they had written "x^y^z", on the other hand...

Comment: It doesn't say anything in the task, only $x^{y^z}$ and that is how I got these two solutions, so the problem is only that the task is not precisly defined?

Comment: @Arthur Well, by the looks of it, the first solution the OP got was the second case I gave, so there does seem to be ambiguity.

Comment: @SimpleArt Ahh, I didn't see that that was how he got the two different answers. As hinted to earlier, it didn't even occur to me to interpret the exponents in that direction. Nice catch.

Comment: The task is precisely defined without any mathematical ambiguity. The expression $x^{y^z}$ means **only** $x^{(y^z)}$. It is a common confusion, though, so I admit that there's a _perceived_ ambiguity there. I think part of learning experience to take away from this question is to learn how the notation for nested exponents actually works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$f(x,y,z) = x^{y^{z}} \text{ then } \frac{\partial}{\partial z} f(x,y,z) = \log(x) y^z \log y x^{y^{z}}$$ And if, $$f(x,y,z) = (x^y)^{z} \text{ then } \frac{\partial}{\partial z} f(x,y,z) = (x^y)^{z} \log(x^y)$$ These results are different due to the different ways the power of $z$ has been executed. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If we have $$x^{y^z}$$ then we get by the chain rule $${x}^{{y}^{z}}{y}^{z}\ln  \left( y \right) \ln  \left( x \right) $$